How to count the number of cells that have been given a certain colour in MS Excel?
I'm trying to identify the number of cells with given colours using a formula. I've found online references such as this https://learnexcel.io/count-colored-cells-excel/ but have been unable to make it work and it seems to require conditional formatting which is not what I want to do.
I want to be able to produce a table like below where the count column of the counting colours table is automatically calculated based on the colour of the rows in the "Table being Counted" table regardless of the contents.
Is there a formula for this? What's the trick?
Tables below to describe what I'm after:


https://trumpexcel.com/count-colored-cells-in-excel/

What determines the coloring of the cells? If it can be replicated with a formula then you should have your answer. If it is just based on "random" selection, then you'll need VBA.

@gns100 while I agree that vba is probably the way to go unless the colour is a result of logic (conditional formatting), it's still possible to count by colour without having to use vba.

Saying it can be done without vba is not completely right basically you are using Excel Macro 4.0 Functions and also Op needs to save the file as .xlsm or .xlsb. Here is the link

Im only interested in formulas dont want to use macros

@MayukhBhattacharya Excel alerts to save as macro file, but it works if you don't.

Excel will alert for saving, but point it is not completely using an Excel Formula. It is using Excel Macro 4.0 so that is the difference. and completely using an excel formula is not possible. @spikey_richie has shared a link on using VBA + Excel Formula with Excel Macro 4.0. OP is asking completely using Excel Formula where OP dont have to save as .xlsm or .xlsb and it will work not without saving in those formats.

While it's likely better to go with a vba solution, I want to point out a formula solution even if the coloring is not the result of logic (conditional formatting):
We need Excel 365 to be able to make this work.
In the Name Manager we create a name: COLOUR and refer to:
=LAMBDA(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,GET.CELL(63,y))))
This will return the number presentation of the background colour of the cells as a spill range.
Next we create another name: COUNTCOLOUR and refer to:
=LAMBDA(x,y,MAP(x,LAMBDA(z,SUM(N(COLOUR(z)=COLOUR(y))))))
This simulates COUNTIF by colour.
We can now use COUNTCOLOUR with the same logic as COUNTIF:

Caveat: Originally, Excel’s color system was based on an index of fewer than 60 colors. The GET.CELL function uses this old color index system, which does not account for the millions of colors available in modern Excel. As a result, different shades or intensities of a color might return the same index number, leading to inaccurate counts if you’re expecting a distinction between these shades

Why is the number 63 in this formula? GET.CELL(63,y) what does it denote?

63 in GET.CELL returns the numeric representation of the background colour of the cell.

@user1605665 let me know if that works for you.

@P.b Sir, it should work!

@P.b I had to add a sum to count colour bother otherwise working.  I could not use Get.Cell when in a cell and when I used a Cell.Get it doesnt return any value.

You can only use it in the name manager, as demonstrated.
